# Add class when redirecting from specific page

Tags: php, jquery, html, url, redirect

Is it possible to add a class to a div on pageload, but ONLY when redirected from a specific link/page?

I have a `<a href="marketing.php" id="openMyMaterialTab"><button class="secondaryAction">See all</button></a>` link on my landingpage, that should add a class to a div on marketing.php on redirect. This class should not be active, when the page is loaded from other links.

Edited for clarification

Comment: Im asking because i have no idea. I've tested some examples found on google without luck , though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your bootstrap page

```
session_start();
// page and classes 
$classes = array(
                    'page1.php' => 'class1',
                    'page2.php' => 'class2',
                    'index.php' => 'class3',
            );


$_SESSION['classes'] = $classes;
```

On each particular page

```
$predefined_classes = $_SESSION['classes'];
$class = "";

if( isset( $predefined_classes[ basename(__FILE__) ] ) ){

    $class = $predefined_classes[ basename(__FILE__) ];
}
```

use this $class now, like.

```
<button class="<?php echo $class; ?>"> </button>
```

Comment: @CarstenAndersen You does not need to use bootstrap its in PHP

Comment: does both of your classes should change according to page